# Edit parsed URLs in NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, url, xpath

Im working on an app where one of the pages shows a websites blog....I have parsed everything into arrays to load into a UITableView. I would ideally like to show the thumbnail images from the YouTube videos in the TableView cells...however the parsed code only contains the embed code for the videos....

Soo....the question is how can I take something like:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/videoID?version=3&feature=player_detailpage
```

and change it to:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/videoID/1.jpg
```

Or possibly a way to only parse the videoID to load into a string with the correct surrounding URL?  Something like:

```
search:@"//embed/[onlytakethevideoID]"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a substring from an URL is a fragile approach, because Google can change their URL scheme at any time.

Consider, instead, creating an `NSURL` object and getting the `pathComponents` array from it. The path contains your video ID, and can be used to build a new URL:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/videoID?version=3&feature=player_detailpage"];
NSArray *myURLPathComps = [myURL pathComponents];
NSString *myVideoID = [myURLPathComps objectAtIndex:[myURLPathComps count]-1];
NSURL *myNewURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/%@/1.jpg", myVideoID]];
```

I think you'll find that this is less likely to break. Google could change their URL host, scheme, etc., but as long as the video ID is in the same part of the path, you should be okay.

Comment: This is the approach I ended up using.  Worked a little better with varying Video ID lengths in my URL...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're asking is how to extract the videoID. I don't know YouTube's url scheme, but if it's like what you've posted above, you can just extract characters 26 through (26 + lengthOfVideoID) from the string and construct a new string, like this:

```
NSRange   videoIDRange = { 26, 26 + kVideoIDLength };
NSString* videoID = [youTubeLink substringWithRange:videoIDRange];
NSString* newURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/%@/1.jpg", videoID];
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Just a heads up....using {26, 26 + kVideoIDLength} returned 26 through 37 (kVideoIDLength = 11).  Changing the range to {26, 11} returned the correct range.  Thanks again!

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that. Good catch.

Comment: What do you do if Google changes the format of their URLs tomorrow, so that this range no longer works?

Comment: Well won't that be a problem for any scheme they come up with? They could then change that. Unless they have a way for you to pass them a URL and have them extract the ID from it, I'm not sure I see a way to fully future-proof this. They do have a [data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api) that could be useful. I don't know anything about it, though.

Answer (score 0):

**The VideoID string can be obtained as the result of evaluationg a single XPath expression**:

```
substring-before(substring-after($theUrl, 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'),
                 '?'
                 )
```

Where `$theUrl` should be substituted with the actual Url.